# Can text in telegram bot's text works as Html attribute?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

```
if (update.getMessage().getText().equalsIgnoreCase("/register")) {
                    try {
                        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
                        sendMessage.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
                        sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(update.getMessage().getMessageId());
                        sendMessage.setText("Press <a href=\"https://sso.***.com/account/register\">" +
                                "HERE</a> to register");
                        execute(sendMessage);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to add Html button to `SendMessage.setText`, but this not work.
Did i do it wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear at all. But i think you can add:

```
sendMessage.enableHtml(true);
```

You can check [Tabnine](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage/setChatId)